# Trigonometric function $f \left( \frac{x}{x - 1} \right) = \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: trigonometry

For all real numbers $x$ except $x=0$ and $x=1$ the function $f(x)$ is defined by
$$f \left( \frac{x}{x - 1} \right) = \frac{1}{x}.$$ Suppose $0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. What is the value of $f(\sec^2t)$?

---

I first set $\sec^2t = \frac{x}{x-1}$ and then plugged it in to WA which told me that $x = \csc^2t$ so that would mean that $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{\csc^2x}.$ However, that turned out to be wrong, so what should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2{\theta}}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{1-\sin^2{\theta}}\right) = f\left(\frac{\csc^2{\theta}}{\csc^2{\theta}-1}\right) = \frac{1}{\csc^2{\theta}} = \sin^2{\theta}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{x}{x-1}$. Then $\displaystyle f(g(x)) = \frac{1}{x}$, so $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{g^{-1}(x)}$. That inverse function is not hard to compute.

Answer (score 1):

You mean $\frac{1}{\csc^2\color{blue}{t}}=\sin^2t$, as per @BastienTourand's change-$t$-to-$\theta$ answer. Alternatively, since $f(y)=1-1/y$, $f(\sec^2t)=1-\cos^2t=\sin^2t$.